# XPATH for all child nodes with different names

Tags: xpath, sgml

I have a parent element with various child elements that I need to keep a count on. The problem I'm having is each child element is different name, so everytime I use count(*) the numbering restarts. I need the numbering to go 1.1, 1.2, 1.3...

The parent tag is `<application>` would be 1, `<ident>` would be 1.1, `<kitapplic>` would be 1.2, and `<tctoproof>` would be 1.3

I thought I could just do a count(child::application) but that didn't work. Your help is appreciated.

```
<application>
    <ident>
        <para>This Technical Order is applicable.</para>
    </ident>
    <kitapplic>
        <kitapptbl>
            <kitapptblrow>
                <model>Model</model>
                <serialno>Serial Number</serialno>
                <kitno>Kit Required</kitno>
            </kitapptblrow>
        </kitapptbl>
    </kitapplic>
    <tctoproof>
        <para>Time Compliance Technical Order (TCTO) verification, in accordance
            with TO 00-5-15, was accomplished 28 August 2019 at Nellis Air Force
        Base with GCS serial number 5147.</para>
    </tctoproof>
</application>
```

Comment: Few questions...Did you mean to tag this as sgml instead of xml? What are you really trying to do (higher level than counting elements)? What is your output supposed to look like? What are you using to execute the XPath with (is it a part of an XSLT?)?

Comment: Yes this is SGM. I'm using Arbortext Styler to create the style sheet. You can specify the element is a numbered type and in it there's the option to use an XPATH expression. The parent tag is <application> would be 1, <ident> would be 1.1, <kitapplic> would be 1.2, and <tctoproof> would be 1.3

Comment: I also tried /Application/child::node() but that didn't work either.

Comment: Maybe count isn't what I need. position(  ) would give me the nodes numbered position in the parent element. But I haven't been able to get it to work.

Comment: It's possible to come up with xpath/xquery expression that would give you the depth of each node; so for example, the two `<para>`s would be each depth `3`, etc. But I'm not sure how to go from that to converting the first `<para>` to "1.1.1" and the second to "1.3.1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XPath, you can use `count` `preceding-sibling` and `concat` to get the desired numbers. Example with `kitapplic` :

```
concat("1.",count(application/kitapplic/preceding-sibling::*)+1)
```

Output : `1.2`

If you need a list with 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 for each child of application element you can do (example in Python) :

```
data = """<application>
    <ident>
        <para>This Technical Order is applicable.</para>
    </ident>
    <kitapplic>
        <kitapptbl>
            <kitapptblrow>
                <model>Model</model>
                <serialno>Serial Number</serialno>
                <kitno>Kit Required</kitno>
            </kitapptblrow>
        </kitapptbl>
    </kitapplic>
    <tctoproof>
        <para>Time Compliance Technical Order (TCTO) verification, in accordance
            with TO 00-5-15, was accomplished 28 August 2019 at Nellis Air Force
        Base with GCS serial number 5147.</para>
    </tctoproof>
</application>"""

import lxml.html
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(data)

for el in tree.xpath("//application/*"):
    print(el.xpath("concat(name(.),' 1.',count(./preceding-sibling::*)+1)"))
```

Output :

```
ident 1.1
kitapplic 1.2
tctoproof 1.3
```

Comment: Thank you that helped a lot